# hard disk won't initialize, showing size as 0.00kb and fatal device hardware error or I/O error

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, disk-management

My hard disk on my laptop wasn't being recognized, so I pulled it out of my laptop(lenovo legion y730) and connected it to another laptop (Microsoft Surface Book). It wasn't responding so I had to clean it and create partition using the cmd diskpart commands. After doing that it worked.

So I was trying to recover my deleted files from my hard drive some days back using ReclaiMe Pro. It worked for a while but after ejecting the hard drive and back in, it either didn't read or took a very long time to read and the reclaime pro kept freezing when it was trying to recognize it for recovery. So I thought of cleaning the hard drive again and creating a partition, because I thought something might had gone wrong along the way.

When I tried the diskpart commands again, my console froze for about an hour without any response when I typed "clean" after selecting the disk of course. I didn't do the "clean all" command so it wasn't meant to take that long.

Eventually, I pulled out the hard drive and when I connected it back in, it showed me Disk 1 Unknown Not initialized(as in the image attached), and also showed me the file size as 0kb in the command prompt console when I typed "list disk"

When I tried initializing with the disk management app or with diskpart in cmd, I get the "the request failed due to a fatal device hardware error" error and when I tried with a windows 7 computer it gave me the I/O device error.

I'm sad my files are gone but right now i just want my hard drive to work. It's just 4 months old. It's a Seagate Barracuda Pro 1tb and the hard drive reader I used is a WD element hard drive reader.

[image: This is a screenshot of the problem]]

Answer (score 1):

Just 4 months old means it is still under warranty - so better use it.

It is not normal for a new drive to fail this hard and indicates a hardware
manufacturing error.
My advice is not to use it, as using it you may too easily lose your data.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am in Ghana and I don't have warranty here. Right now I do not care about the data. I just want it to work.

Comment: Isn't there a fix that can be done for this? It isn't giving the hardware click sound. So I feel there's still hope for it.

Comment: I don't know of a software solution for a disk that cannot be initialized. You might need a (qualified) technician that knows this disk.